# How to connect to remote Oracle DB with PL/SQL Developer?

Tags: database, oracle, plsqldeveloper, authentication

I have a database "TEST", to which I connect at address 123.45.67.89:1521.

How do I connect to it using PL/SQL Developer?

Comment: Did you set up your `TNSNAMES.ora` file? http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Tnsnames.ora

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I would recommend creating a TNSNAMES.ORA file. From your Oracle Client install directory, navigate to NETWORK\ADMIN. You may already have a file called TNSNAMES.ORA, if so edit it, else create it using your favorite text editor.

Next, simply add an entry like this:

```
MYDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 123.45.67.89)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = TEST)(SERVER = DEDICATED))
  )
```

You can change MYDB to whatever you like, this is the identifier that applications will will use to find the database using the info from TNSNAMES.

Finally, login with MYDB as your database in PL/SQL Developer. It should automatically find the connection string in the TNSNAMES.ORA.

If that does not work, hit Help->About then click the icon with an "i" in it in the upper-lefthand corner. The fourth tab is the "TNS Names" tab, check it to confirm that it is loading the proper TNSNAMES.ORA file. If it is not, you may have multiple Oracle installations on your computer, and you will need to find the one that is in use.

Answer (score 49):

In the "database" section of the logon dialog box, enter `//hostname.domain:port/database`, in your case `//123.45.67.89:1521/TEST`  - this assumes that you don't want to set up a `tnsnames.ora` file/entry for some reason.

Also make sure the firewall settings on your server are not blocking port `1521`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not the TNS file, in PLSQL Developer, if you don't have the oracle installation, you need to provide the location of the OCI.DLL file.

In PLSQL DEV app go to Tools-Preferences-Oracle/connections-OCI Library.

In my case I put the next address `C:\Oracle\InstantClient-win32-11.2.0.1.0\oci.dll`.

If have Weblogic app installed, I didnt tried but if you want try to put the next location

`C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\server\adr`.

Comment: Hi Ignacio & welcome. I've voted your answer up doing my "first post" reviewing rounds as it seems to the point and well written (as a Java dev I cannot see if it is correct though). You can check the changes that andrewsi made by clicking on the date/time of the edit. Thanks for joining us :)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Richard Cresswells and dpbradleys answer:
If you neither want to create a TNS name nor the '//123.45.67.89:1521/Test' input works (some configurations wont), you can put

```
(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 123.45.67.89)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = TEST)(SERVER = DEDICATED)))
```

(as one line) into the 'database' section of the login dialog.

Answer (score 2):

I am facing to this problem so many times till I have **32bit** PL/SQL Developer and **64bit** Oracle DB or Oracle Client.

The solution is:

1. **install a 32bit client.**
2. set PLSQL DEV-Tools-Preferencies-Oracle Home to new 32bit client Home
3. set PLSQL DEV-Tools-Preferencies-OCI to new 32 bit home /bin/oci.dll For example: c:\app\admin\product\11.2.0\client_1\BIN\oci.dll
4. Save and restart PLSQL DEV.

Edit or create a TNSNAMES.ORA file in c:\app\admin\product\11.2.0\client_1\NETWORK\admin folder like mentioned above.

Try with TNSPING in console like

> C:>tnsping ORCL

If still have problem, set the **TNS_ADMIN Enviroment properties** value pointing to the folder where the TNSNAMES.ORA  located,  like: c:\app\admin\product\11.2.0\client_1\network\admin

Answer (score 1):

```
Username : username
Password : password
Database : //123.45.67.89:1521/TEST
Connect as : Normal
```

this work for me and (version 13.0.6.1911 64 bit)

Comment: Welcome to SO, might your answer is correct, but code sample is expected to show how to do that.

Comment: I am used by GUI for test 1st step If the correct will can go to next step.