# create a link with sql developer on windows to a database oracle on VM

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

i have a database on my VM Oracle Linux Server 7.2. I check that the database is up with lsnrctl status:

```
[oracle@localhost ~]$ lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on 27-JUN-2017 20:07:56

Copyright (c) 1991, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1522)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
Start Date                27-JUN-2017 19:48:31
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 19 min. 25 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/localhost/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1522)))
Services Summary...
Service "Oracle12" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ORCL", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

After i start the listener with lsnrctl start:

```
[oracle@localhost ~]$ lsnrctl start

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 12.2.0.1.0 - Production on 27-JUN-2017 20:11:30

Copyright (c) 1991, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

TNS-01106: Listener using listener name LISTENER has already been started
```

How i can create a connection with SQL Developer to the database on my VM??

[image]

Comment: Connecting to an Oracle Database running on a VM is exactly the same as connecting to it if it was on physical hardware.  As long as you can ping the VM from the client and open up port 1522 (the port your listener is using) in the firewall on the VM for incoming connections.

Comment: how i can connecting to database on VM?Where i try the information to insert into the connection link as user, password,host,sid,port and connection type?

Comment: Did you do any research at all?  Tons of articles out there including several questions/answers from this site: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108320/how-to-connect-to-oracle-11g-database-remotely and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30232665/how-to-access-oracle-database-over-network and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832908/how-to-connect-to-remote-oracle-db-with-pl-sql-developer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect to remote Oracle DB with PL/SQL Developer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832908/how-to-connect-to-remote-oracle-db-with-pl-sql-developer)

Comment: i connect my db that is on VM with sql delevoper install on my VM. I try to create the same connection with the same settings but it not work. The error is Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor. What i can do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661610/tns-12505-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-sid-given-in-connect-descript and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23209962/ora-12505-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-sid-given-in-connect-des