# Can I create a connection without modifying tnsnames.ora?

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

Can I create a connection without modifying tnsnames.ora?

I have a db in a remote server which is accesible using ping or telnet. However, I don't have the permissions to modify the tnsnames.ora file.

How could I access the db using PL/SQL Developer?

Comment: Yes you can  google "oracle connection string without tnsnames" and you will see some options

Comment: You can create a `tnsnames.ora` file in your home directory. With environment variable `TNS_ADMIN` you can point to any folder.

Comment: You can try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1833413/2856136), which basically uses Oracle's [EZCONNECT](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/EZCONNECT) method.

Answer (score 1):

You can also write the whole connect string in the "database" field (you must edit it in order to be on a single line of text), instead of using its alias defined in tnsnames.ora

Like in this example: 
[image: Like this]